# Django Test Client: Test that context is a RequestContext object

Tags: django

is there a way to test that the response.context object the test client returns, a RequestContext object is? I checked the source code and it seems they wrap the context in a ContextList object.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the ContextList is not empty, then check the item which is a `RequestContext` object:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

response = client.post(...)
context_list = response.context

for context in context_list:
    if isinstance(context, RequestContext):
        # do some more test checks here
```